# Matching problems

Tags: regex, perl

Hello Can anyone help me with this problem
I have to match the following line :

```
B14-1190                 COMBINATION                             1695 BROADWAY                         3,500.00                    179.74               179.74
```

I used this regex

```
^(B\d{2}-\d{4})\s{5,}(COMBINATION)\s{10,}(\d{2,4}\s.*)\s{2,}(\d{2,4}.*)\s{2,}(\d{2,4}.*)\s{2,}(\d{2,4}.*)
```

I don't get what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

I want to get out : `B14-1190`
                    `COMBINATION`
                    `1695 BROADWAY`
                    `3,500.00`
                    `179.74`
                    `179.74`

Comment: What do you want to get out of the regex?

Comment: you forget the string `BROADWAY`.

Comment: .* will anyways eat up everything.should be .*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`,` is not a digit (does not match \d)

```
^(B\d{2}-\d{4})\s{5,}(COMBINATION)\s{10,}(\d{2,4}\s.*)\s{2,}([\d,.]{2,4}.*)\s{2,}([\d,.]{2,4}.*)\s{2,}([\d,.]{2,4}.*)
```

works.

You should consider matching `\S*` rather than `.*` to capture the tail end of fields, so you know that you are only capturing one field at a time.

Comment: Why you had to put `[\d,]` only there. I mean wouldn't it have been more ok if I put on the others too? Like this `[\d.]`?

Comment: Yes [\d,.] is good for matching all numbers in this format (I was not sure if you were intentionally matching only the integer part). And it would make sense to use the same pattern for all 3 numeric fields. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily without a complex regex:

```
my $string = "B14-1190                 COMBINATION                             1695 BROADWAY                         3,500.00                    179.74               179.74";

my @items = split(/\s{2,}/, $string);
```